# How do I duplicate values in jq?

Tags: jq

I am trying to duplicate the values that I've received in jq.
For example: If I enter ".address", I get a value "Times Square, New York"

I want to duplicate it so that it gives me the values:

"Times Square, New York"
"Times Square, New York"
"Times Square, New York"
"Times Square, New York"

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to create a stream of 4 arbitrary items, e.g. numbers using `range`, store them in a variable to not affect the context, and provide your output for each:

```bash
range(4) as $_ | .address
```

You can also use the [comma operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Comma:,) `,` to manually compile your stream:

```bash
.address, .address, .address, .address
```

Comment: thanks, this is really useful! Can I add to the range, the length of an array? 
If so what would be the command to do that?

Comment: If your array is stored in `$a`, you can use `range($a | length)`. Or just iterate over the array instead of those numbers `$a[] as $_ | .address`